# Converting the contents of a linked list to string (using stringstream) but cannot figure out how to iterate through list c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, iteration, tostring

I am currently trying to write a function that will convert the data inside a linked list to a string using stringstream. I cannot figure out how to do it but have started the function with minimal functionality. How could I better write my function to achieve this?

SList.cpp:

```
/*
 * SList.cpp
 *
 * written by Carlos D. Escobedo
 * created on 26 Oct
 *
 * References: programmingforums.org (printing linked lists), stackoverflow
 *             (.h file linking issues)
 */

#include "SList.h"


SList::SList() {
    head = NULL;
    size = 0;
}

SList::~SList() {
    SList::clear();
    delete head;
}

void SList::insertHead(int value) {
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = new SLNode(value);
    } else {
        SLNode* temp = new SLNode(value);
        temp->setNextNode(head);
        head = temp;
    }
    size++;
}

void SList::removeHead() {
    if (head != NULL) {
        head = NULL;  
        size--;
    }
}

void SList::clear() {
    head = NULL;
}

unsigned int SList::getSize() const {
    return size;
}

string SList::toString() const {
    stringstream ss;
    if (head != NULL) {
        ss.str("");
    } else {
        int i = 1;
        for (SLNode* n = head; n != NULL; n->getNextNode()) {
            if  (i < (size - 1))
                ss << n->getContents() << ", ";
            ss << n->getContents();
            i++;
        }
    }
    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: Assuming that everything is implemented correct, my assumptions are correct, and that `getNextNode()` return the pointer to the next node (or NULL if it is the end of the list), in the `for` you can change the `n->getNextNode()` to `n = n->getNextNode()`.

Comment: `if (head != NULL) {` Shouldn't that be `if (head == NULL) {`? (Line 2 of `toString`)

Comment: Why are you not using `std::list`? Iterating over standard containers always follows the same syntax, be it `std::list`, `std::vector`, or any other standard container.

Comment: @Johny Mopp yes!! that should be! good catch on that, thank you.

Comment: ^ because it's homework/assignment.

Comment: @cdonat I am not using std::list because I didin't even know that was a thing. I am going to have to research it. thank you

Comment: Remove head seems strange. Shouldn't it be `head = head->getNextNode()` and before that a `delete head`

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't homework you should drop the homemade list and use a standard container like vector or list.

Example for vector

```
// vector of string
std::vector<std::string> stringVector;

// add strings
stringVector.push_back("text");
stringVector.push_back("more text");

// iterate all
for (auto& str : stringVector)
{
    // do something with str
    // example:
    std::cout << str;
}
```

There is a number of standard containers in c++, e.g. vector, list, deque, array. Each have different pros and cons. You need to learn them to write c++

Comment: It was homework 2 weeks ago. I can't turn it in anymore but I still want to learn how to create and manipulate a homemade linked list.

Comment: In that case you should write a list based on a template and forget the stringstream to start with. A list have some basic functionality like add and remove element, retrieve elements, iterate list, etc which should be implemented without knowing the type of element. Do that first using a template.